# radius of circle tangent to sphere which obscures that sphere

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles

A circular disc sits tangential to the surface of a sphere, how big does it have to be to obscure that sphere from a given point of view?

Or, in two dimensions:

[image]

Given $d$ and $r$, what is $h$?

Comment: What symbol do you suggest for the radius of the sphere?

Comment: It's $r$. Why, is that surprising?

Comment: Cause, I took $r$ to be the smaller segment where it is labeled and not the entire green segment.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

From similar triangles:
$$
h:d=r:\sqrt{(r+d)^2-r^2}.
$$

Comment: Have you checked the result? This comes out less than my answer, and I have checked mine graphically.

Comment: In my answer $r$ is the radius of the sphere, green in the diagram (your $R$) and the result is identical with yours.

Comment: I thought little $r$ is the distance between the contact line and the circle. My bad. That would simplify the calculation indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If the radius of the sphere is $r$ and the distanbce between the sphere and the eye is $d$ then $$\boxed{h = r\, \sqrt{ \frac{d}{2 r+d} } }$$

**Why?**

[image: fig]

The small orange line above has length $k = \frac{r^2}{r+d}$

Considering the angle $\theta$ at the eye and at the contact point we have

$$\sin(\theta) = \frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2+d^2}} = \frac{k}{r} $$

which is solved for $h = \frac{d k}{\sqrt{r^2-k^2}} = \frac{r \sqrt{d}}{\sqrt{2 r+d}}$.

---

### Example

A unit sphere $R=1$ and an eye a distance $d=0.8$ above the surface.

$$ h = 1 \sqrt{ \frac{0.8}{2+0.8} } = \sqrt{\frac{2}{7}} = 0.534522\;\; \checkmark $$

[image: exmpl]